# Sending an array to PHP via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I declare my array:

```
p.myArray = [];
```

I add to the array in a loop:

```
 self.myArray.push($(this).data('id')); // [1,2,3,4]
```

I then send this via AJAX to PHP via POST:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/gateway',
    data: {data: self.myArray}, 
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
})
```

I was wondering, do I need to have a key/value pair? Can I just send through the array? Does it need serialising?

Comment: You do need a key/value pair, but you're sending one. The key is `data`, the value is the array. You code should work - are you having issues with it?

Comment: No issues, I was just wondering if I had to have a key/value pair AND if I need to seralize the array?

Comment: jQuery will serialise the array for you, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: if you are working with static inputs use `$('#formid').serialize();` , and if you are working with dynamic variables u have to set every key inside the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing an object to `data` will cause jQuery to serialise it for you.

The array will be available in `$_POST['data'][]`

---

It would be clearer if you didn't use the same name for different things.

```
data: { theArray: self.myArray },
```

goes to:

```
$_POST['theArray'][]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are using `dataType: 'json'` your PHP script will have to return JSON serialised data or jQuery will ignore the response.

i.e:

```
$myArray = $_POST['myArray'];
echo json_encode($myArray);
```